# Biztalk 2009 sql server 2008 SP1?

Tags: sql-server-2008, biztalk-2009

Is service pack 1 of SQL 2008 needed for Biztalk 2009 ?

Or is the SQL 2008 Enterprise install sufficient ?

The install guide doesn't mention SP1 for SQL 2008 (Enterprise)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need SP1 to install and use biztalk 2009.  However SP1 should be on your roadmap to install on the server as a general best practice.

Comment: I just installed SQL 2008 Enterprise, and I want to install SP then before BT2009 gets installed, that shouldn't be a problem then I think...